# Will the graduate school that I've been accepted to reconsider my admissions offer?

Tags: graduate-school

I was accepted into a graduate school and intend on going, but I got a B- in a chemistry course and now I'm worried about this. I don't think that the rest of my grades will be this low. My GPA > 3.5 currently. The last time I made a B- was over two years ago. The requirements for matriculation are getting a BS/BA and finishing with good standing.

Comment: Read the fine print of your acceptance letter.  In the U.S., as long as you keep to whatever conditions were stated there, you should be okay.

Comment: Congratulations on the acceptance. Chill out and go take a blissful walk.

Comment: @mehrdad : You aren't supposed to answer questions in comments. You should expand on this excellent answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Almost certainly not. Every program/department/country is a little different, but in general I'd say a single lower-than-average grade at the last minute isn't a signal that someone isn't ready for graduate school. Especially in situations where the acceptance was based on far more than grades: statements of purpose, letters of recommendation, fit with the department, etc. If you failed a bunch of courses in your final semester, that *might* be seen as a red flag, but a single B- isn't likely to faze anyone in the slightest. You'd need a lot more than that to threaten your good standing (which in my experience is taken to mean 'not in any kind of trouble academically or otherwise').